# PHP: подскажите, плз, как обращаться к нужному элементу массива объектов [узел: узел: узел]?

Tags: php, массивы, объекты, динамические-массивы, синтаксис

Получил в переменную следующий массив объектов:

```
Array ( [0] => RarEntry Object ( [rarfile:RarEntry:private] => RarArchive Object ( ) [position:RarEntry:private] =>
```

К сожалению, больше отрывок не могу привести (

Никогда раньше не сталкивался со структурой такого типа [узел: узел: узел].

Если у меня весь такой массив лежит в переменной $h, то как мне обратиться на PHP к тому, что лежит, допустим, в private, если в квадратных скобках не только оно одно... пробовал как-то так $h[0]->{private}->, но не получилось... Подскажите, что это за структура [узел: узел: узел] (как называется, чтобы гуглить), а также: как в ней с помощью PHP можно обратиться к нужному элементу?

Comment: Это приватные элементы класса, их просто так не достать. rarfile -это приватное свойство класса RarEntry. Читайте описание класса - возможно, есть метод, который это свойство возвращает

Comment: Почему же не достать - через рефлекторы можно. Но тут больше структура похожа на `xml` там есть такие узлы

Comment: `class MyClass { private $t = 25; }  print_r(new MyClass()); даст MyClass Object ( [t:MyClass:private] => 25 )`

Comment: @phpBear можно, но не как элемент массива, естественно

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.rar.php ?